# React Demo - Installation Failed : Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.

Trying to create demo project & it is failed.

```
MacBook-Pro react-demo $ npx create-react-app .
npx: installed 98 in 3.718s

Creating a new React app in /Users/abc/Sites/react-demo.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.19.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /Users/abc/Sites/react-demo has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting
```

react-demo/ from /Users/abc/Sites
Done.

Comment: Delete react-demo folder and use 'npx create-react-app react-demo' command.

Comment: Still same error @ZainUlHassan

Answer (score 0):

In my system I have installed `yarn` & `npm` both.

So I think it it taking priority to `yarn` over `npm`.

```
npm update yarn -g
```

Above command resolved my issue.

Using `yarn start`.

Answer (score 0):

clea cache use:

```sh
yarn cache clean
```

I have to run this when the problem come out.
The problem will come again. I dont know how to setup it for fever.